# I'm trying to identify a distribution presented to me as the "Van Loon distribution".

Tags: probability-distributions

My professor's book on Electrical Measurements presents 3 distributions that model the probability density function of the error an observation is expected to have given a set of already obtained observations.

These are the normal distribution, the "Van Loon" distribution and the Laplace distribution. The problem is that I can't find any other reference to a Van Loon distribution on Google and I suspect my professor is using a lesser known name for an otherwise common distribution.

The distribution is:
$$\psi(\delta) = \frac{\alpha e^{\alpha \delta}}{(1+e^{\alpha \delta})^2}$$

Has anyone seen this distribution before?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a probability density on the interval $\delta\ge0\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: No it is defined for all $ \delta \in \Bbb {R} $

Comment: ok, I just noticed that this is an even function of $\delta. \qquad$

Comment: I'd be very interested if there is a reference for this name "Van Loon distribution", for the [logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution) (published paper, book or whatever).

Comment: Sometimes people mention why it is a mistake to "accept" an answer too quickly.

Comment: Anything to do with [Emiel van Loon](http://www.uva.nl/profiel/l/o/e.e.vanloon/e.e.vanloon.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be the [logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution) with location $\mu=0$ and scale $s = 1/\alpha$. As noted by Michael Hardy in the comments, the PDF is symmetric [about $\mu$].

Answer (score 9):

This is the logistic distribution.
\begin{align}
\int_0^\delta \frac {\alpha e^{\alpha\eta}}{(1+ e^{\alpha\eta})^2} \,d\eta = \int_2^{1+e^{\alpha\delta}} \frac{du}{u^2} = \frac 1 2 - \frac 1 {1+e^{\alpha\delta}} \to \frac 1 2 \text{ as } \delta\to+\infty.
\end{align}
Since the density is an even function, as may be checked with a bit of algebra, we have
$$
p=\int_{-\infty}^\delta \psi(\eta)\,d\eta = 1 - \frac 1 {1+e^{\alpha\delta}} = \frac 1 {1 + e^{-\alpha\delta}} = \text{a logistic function of }\delta.
$$
From this it follows that
$$
\delta = \frac 1 \alpha \log \frac p {1-p} = \frac 1 \alpha \operatorname{logit} p.
$$
"Logit" is conventionally pronounced with a "long o" as in "boat" and a soft "g" sounding like the "j" in "jet", and the stress on the first syllable.

Google the terms "logistic function" and "logistic distribution."

Comment: Pretty sure that either the third or the fourth expression in your second equation has a sign error somewhere.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert : You're right; the second one should not have had a minus sign in the exponent.